# How to reorder a string (no matter how it is) using Python REGEX

Tags: python, regex, capturing-group

I'm pretty newbie playing REGEX and I'm having a hard time... I'm trying to reorder a string using Python re. Here's a simple example, this is what I have:

```
str = "one two three for"
```

But the problem is: I don't know the order. It could be `"three two for one"` sometimes, it could be `"for three two one"`, `"one for two three`" or whatever... I just need a single regex to make it "one two three for" no matter what. I think of something like this:

```
str = re.sub(r"some regex here", "\1 \2 \3 \4", str)  #/1 => one, /2 => two, /3 => three, /4 => for
```

I don't even know if it makes sense or if it's possible somehow haha but I think you guys understood me. So, how would you do this? 
Thanks a lot!

Comment: Why it is "for" not "four"?

Comment: is it compulsory to do it with regex?

Comment: I suggest you change your string to `"one two three four"` or `"one two three fire!"`.

Comment: sorry typo hahaa.. yes I think it is compulsory unfortunately

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This seems like a little brute force but here it is,
Trying to match `one or two or three` one after the other

**Code:**

```
import re 
sentences = ['some sentence -> one two three',
             'some other sentence ->  two three one ',
             'this is a different ->  three two one',
             'statment -> three one two',
             'this is one two statement -> two one three']
for sentence in sentences:
    print(re.sub("(one|two|three)\s+(one|two|three)\s+(one|two|three)", "one two three", sentence))
```

**Output:**

```
some sentence -> one two three
some other sentence ->  one two three 
this is a different ->  one two three
statment -> one two three
this is one two statement -> one two three
```

Answer (score -1):

Here is what you can do:

```
import re
s = "one two three for"
r = re.compile('(\S* )(\S* )(\S* )(\S*)')
print(r.sub(r'\2\1\3\4',s))
```

Output:

```
two one three for
```

Comment: Your regex is configured for "one two three for" only. I'm trying to write a regex that is going to rearrange the phrase no matter the order of the words.

Comment: @EduardoFranco Fixed it!